# Why won't this align middle or bottom?

Tags: css, inline, vertical-alignment

OK, so my stupid little login form almost looks how I want it to look. (This is basically my first CSS project ever and first HTML project since <strike>updating</strike> attempting to update my 15 year old HTML skills.)  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the "forgot password?" link to move down, either aligned with the middle or bottom of the "Login" button.  I've tried moving the `display: inline;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to all kinds of different selectors and none of them work!  I've even tried setting the height of the anchor and/or the `<li>` elements.  I don't understand what the deal is!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
form.login {
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
form.login fieldset{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 348px;
    height: 90px;
}
form.login fieldset legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
form.login fieldset ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
form.login fieldset fieldset {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
form.login fieldset fieldset li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 165px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
form.login input {
    width: 165px;
}
form.login label {
    display: none;
}
form.login a:link, 
form.login a:visited {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
form.login a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
form.login a:active {
    color: blue;
}
form.login fieldset ul fieldset li button#submitLogin {
    float: right;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formstyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="login">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <ul>
            <fieldset>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
                </li>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <li>
                    <a href="resetpass.php">Forgot Password?</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <button id="submitLogin" value="submit" name="submitLogin" type="submit">Login</button>
                </li>
            </fieldset>
        </ul>
        </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: 
[Here's a screen shot of what it looks like with the code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huXdT.png)

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QRNBg/

Comment: Why do you have `fieldset`s within `ul` surround `li`s?

Comment: Well, initially it was because I wanted to be able to stack the two text inputs on the left and stack the other two elements to the right of them, but I just tried to revert it and take a screenshot and discovered that I must have broken that functionality somewhere along the way.  If I commit to leaving it formatted basically the way it is now, I suppose I can simplify the HTML pretty substantially.

Comment: See my answer. I've adjusted your markup and css.

Comment: I fixed some issues I found when I looked at it in Chrome. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your markup to remove the `fieldset`s and to make the style's more consistent. What I am doing here is making the `li`'s all half of the `width` and `height` of the `UL`. That way, if you want to changed the `fieldset`'s `height` and/or `width`, you just have to change the one spot and maybe tweak your other styles.

I also condensed and removed some other unnecessary property declarations (`padding: 0 0 0 0` to `padding: 0`). Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT**

I worked on it to make it more consistent between Chrome and Firefox.

And I actually think you'd be better putting the height on the `li` elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/QRNBg/13/

Try viewing the above and run it while commenting out the `display: none` on the CSS `.hide` class declaration.

**CSS**

```
form.login {
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 20px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
form.login fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
}
form.login fieldset legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
form.login fieldset ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90px;
    width: 348px;
}
form.login fieldset ul li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 45%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
form.login input {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
form.login input,
form.login li.common a {
    width: 93%;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
}
form.login .hide {
    display: none;
}
form.login a:link, 
form.login a:visited {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
form.login a:hover,
form.login a:active {
    color: blue;
}
form.login li.common {
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 2.5em;
}
#submitLogin {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 5px 0 -5px;
}
#submitLogin button {
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="login">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="hide">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
        </li>
        <li class="hide">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
        </li>
        <li class="common">
            <a href="resetpass.php">Forgot Password?</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submitLogin" class="common">
            <button value="submit" name="submitLogin" type="submit">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QRNBg/11/

Comment: You rock man!  I soooo appreciate that!  I'm going to play with it tomorrow and may have a question or two.
Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I tried the link in your edit and I love how it transitions with the labels unhidden.  That's fantastic.  The only issue is, for some reason "forgot password" takes up two lines for me (regardless of the lables)... see here: 

http://i.imgur.com/2rMn3.png and here: 

http://i.imgur.com/34abn.png
Thanks again!

Comment: It's because the font is to big for the box (which the `Forget Password` box is `width: 50%`). One way of resolving that is to set that row (`class="common"`) to be `width: 70%` and then set the `#submitLogin` button to be `width: 30%`, so the `Forget Password` text has more room to expand: http://jsfiddle.net/QRNBg/16/

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Jared - I could have swore I posted this yesterday AM.  Anyway, I take it it's not bad form to allow elements to wrap into place provided their container is a fixed width?  (I was trying to locate the elements and then shrink their container without moving the elements.  I felt like I was playing with a Rubix Cube!)

Comment: No, it's not bad form, it's how floats are meant to work (hence the term `float`). `fieldset`s in `UL` containing `li`s is, though, and I believe it's also not valid markup. I see you marked the other answer as the accepted answer; could you at least give me an upvote? I spent quite a bit of time on this answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry man.  This is my first time posting here and the format is about as natural to me as CCS!  It looks like I can't upvote until I have enough reputation, but I _think_ I switched the accepted answers since yours was really the one I went with.  I appreciate all your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<li class="middle">
     <a href="resetpass.php">Forgot Password?</a>
</li>
<li class="middle">
     <button id="submitLogin" value="submit" name="submitLogin" type="submit">Login</button>
</li>
```

and add this to your css:

```
.middle {
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

This explicitly gives it a set-height and and then through the `line-height`property tells it to center the text and form objects in the li vertically.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank's didn't think about it breaking the floats... i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Trying it now, but why the additional class? Can't all the `<li>` elements be styled that way?

Comment: Oh, I think I spoke too soon!  It works!
Thank you all very much!

If you want to continue pointing out other issues with the code, please... feel free =)

Comment: @JeepFreak I did originally style all the `li` elements but adding a height to them seems to break their floats with your current layout. Glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you want it beside the login button, yet you define it in an 'li' tag before the login button?  have you tried putting that anchor in the same 'li'?  using a 'table' and putting them in the same 'tr' would work for sure.

Comment: @digrasse - I did it that way so I could change the style easily (mainly so that I could stack the two text inputs and then stack the other two elements to the right of the two inputs).

Comment: Table-based layouts are not really encouraged anymore.

Comment: That's what I've read, which is why I was trying to avoid the table route.

Comment: yeah - i know about using tables for non-tabular data is not a best-practice.  but i know from experience that trying to force alignment with floats and the like are brittle and can be browser specific.  if the answers posted work, by all means go with them.

Comment: @dlgrasse, ignoring IE 6, aligning elements with properly written HTML/CSS using floats and the like is not brittle and work very well cross-browser these days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix. http://jsfiddle.net/xNAnz/

I offset the `li` 10px from the top.